# awk, how to pass in a list of files based on a condition?

Tags: awk

I was wondering if there is any way to pass in a file list to awk. The file list has thousands of files and I am using a grep -l to find a subset of files I am interested in passing to awk

E.g.,

```
grep -l id file-*.csv
file-1.csv
file-2.csv

$ cat file-1.csv
id,col_1,col_2
1,abc,100
2,def,200

$ cat file-2.csv
id,col_1,col_2
3,xyz,1000
4,hij,2000
```

If I do

```
$ awk -F, '{print $2,$3}' file-1.csv file-2.csv | grep -v col
abc 100
def 200
xyz 1000
hij 2000
```

it works how I would want but seeing as there are too many files to manually do like this

```
file-1.csv file-2.csv
```

I was wondering if there is a way to pass in the result of the...

```
grep -l id file-*.csv
```

Edit:

```
grep -l id
```

is the condition. Each file has a header but only some have 'id' in the header so I can't use the file-*.csv wildcard in the awk statement.

If I did an ls on file-*.csv I would end up with more the file-1.csv and file-2.csv.

e.g.,

```
$ cat file-3.csv 
name,col,num
a1,hij,3000
b2,lmn,50000

$ ls -l file-*.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 tp  staff  35 20 Sep 18:50 file-1.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 tp  staff  37 20 Sep 18:51 file-2.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 tp  staff  38 20 Sep 18:52 file-3.csv

$ grep -l id file-*.csv
file-1.csv
file-2.csv
```

Comment: Just `awk -F, '{print $2,$3}' file-*.csv`

Comment: @Ed Morton, added  an edit to hopefully clarify the confusion in original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1{print $2,$3}' $(grep -l id file-*.csv)
```

(This will not work if any of your filenames contain whitespace.)

Comment: Thanks, works nicely. No whitespace in my filenames so all good there but thanks for the warning.

Comment: It will also fail if `id` appears in some string on some line other than the first line of some file, e.g. if line 2 of file3 in the question was `a1,hid,3000` instead of `a1,hij,3000` then the grep would feed it to the awk script. For this to be robust you need a full match on a whole field, not a partial match, and it's got to be on just the first line of the file, not just any line of the file and you just can't do that with grep alone.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the output you show under "If I do", it sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
 awk -F, 'FNR>1{print $2,$3}' file-*.csv
```

but your question isn't clear so it's a guess.

Given your updated question all you need with GNU awk for `nextfile` is:

```
 awk -F, 'FNR==1{if ($1 != "id") nextfile} {print $2,$3}' file-*.csv
```

and with any awk (but less efficiently than with GNU awk):

```
 awk -F, 'FNR==1{f=($1=="id"?1:0); next} f{print $2,$3}' file-*.csv
```

Comment: Added edit to help clarify why I can't use file-*.csv. Thanks.

Comment: OK I added how to do what you want with awk.

Comment: Thanks, strangely the nextfile or next doesn't seem to work for me. I am running GNU Awk 4.0.2. I will play around with what you gave me to see if figure out why it is not working.

Comment: You're welcome. Both of those constructs definitely do work in all versions of gawk. If you explain in what way they don't seem to work for you then maybe I can help. Try `seq 3 | awk '{print;nextfile}'` and `seq 3 | awk 'f{next} {print;f=1}'` - was the output `1` for both of them? If so then both constructs work as intended, if not then your awk is broken.

Comment: I get a 1 from running both those tests. When I ran the two awk statements nothing returned. I will try them again, I might have done something silly. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the good news is the tool is working just fine. The bad news is - it's all your fault :-).

Answer (score 1):

To find the files with `id` field, merge/output their contents excluding the lines with field `id`:

**grep** trick:

```
grep --no-group-separator -hA 1000000 'id' file-*.csv | grep -v 'id'
```

- `-h` - suppress the prefixing the file names on output
- `-A num` - print *num* lines of trailing context after matching line(s). `1000000` - considered as maximal number of line which, presumably, will not be exceeded(you may adjust it in case if you really have files with more than 1000000 lines)

---

The output (for 2 sample files from the question):

```
1,abc,100
2,def,200
3,xyz,1000
4,hij,2000
```

Comment: I get an error on that grep statement running on mac...grep: unrecognized option `--no-group-separator'. I modified the statement to grep -hA 1000000 'id' file-*.csv | egrep -v 'id|--' and it seems to work. Can you explain the -hA 1000000? Is it defining a block size on finding 'id'? Thanks.

Comment: @antimuon, yes, see my explanation